# script sending many emails

Tags: php, email

I want to send the content of a page to my email... so i am trying this code

```
<?php

$to  = 'hatim.makki@gmail.com';
$subject = 'JYBExpo Report';

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

$message = file_get_contents('http://jybexpo.com/cms/?page_id=53&print=1');

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

but this code sent me more than 20 emails

how to make it send only one email?
can any one help me?

Comment: you mean 20 copies of the email? or does it break down the content into 20 parts and send you an email for each part?

Answer (score 0):

Reason it is sending multiple emails is because your template is being called multiple times, everytime your template is called the mail script initiates and sends you a new email.

Comment: how are you initiating the script, i mean how are you actually trying to trigger this script ?

Comment: the page sendreport.php only containing that script

Comment: does all the emails have same content ?

Comment: is this the only code, if there's anymore code to it could you paste the whole code ?